# Performance issue on DateTime to :p__linq__0 parameterization

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq

While working on a query tuning issue, I encountered a strange issue.

```
query = trans.Where(w => w.STARTDATE >= mStartDate);
```

Using above query, I got a parameterized sql on DB side such as:

```
WHERE (("Extent1"."TRANLOCALDT" >= :p__linq__0)
```

I wonder if I can make this generated SQL nonparametric on the DB side whit optimizing query on the c# side.

**Edit 1:**

I know that parameterization is a good way for caching queries for future usages.
According to the comments below, I look at plans for generated SQL queries via Oracle SQL Developer. Because of that, I mentioned it as a performance issue.

Cost of the query with parameters is *4582*.

Cost of the query without parameter is *4*.

Comment: And why is that perfomance issue? Parametrized queries like this are better for plan caching, so that should be perfomance improvement, not issue.

Comment: Are the dates string or DateTime objects?  The type in the c# and the SQL database must be the same.

Comment: @Evk : I don't see performance issue but sometime, we need to be careful with parameter sniffing as well. plan caching based on parameters makes query to run in same bad plan even if the query can generate better plan. In that case, I'll go with recompile hint

Comment: @Evk, I edited the question for further explanation about the performance improvement.

Comment: @jdweng As it is described on [Oracle Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings), the type in the c# is DateTime, and it is Timestamp(6) in the Oracle.

Comment: Using no parameter is the same as with excel using General Format. General Format excel guesses type of data and often numbers are changed to dates and dates are changed to numbers.Net library it depends on the database driver how the driver is designed what happens when you do not declare the data type.I do not work with Oracle (mostly excel, access, and SQL) but a database has a schema and if schema it not used it is guessing like excel General Format:See source :https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbProviderFactoriesConfigurationHandler.cs,9657384cacec3b10

Comment: I looked further at source code.  If the parameter type is null it just returns.  Otherwise is does a lot of processing.  It first checks each type in a switch/case.  Then it processes the type with more code.  See : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/OleDb/ColumnBinding.cs,43ae7338b665cde9

Comment: It's possible, but quite complicated. Literals will be non-parametrized (for example: `trans.Where(w => w.STARTDATE >= new DateTime(2017,1,1))` will have 2017-01-01 value inline), but when you reference external variable (`mStartDate`) - it will be parametrized.